# Passing date using $this->url in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have taken following code from my template file,

```
<a onclick="previewPop('<?= $this->url(array('controller'=>'report', 'action'=>'generatepreview','report_date'=>str_replace("%2F", "/", urlencode($this->report_dt))), 'default', true)?>')" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Preview">Preview</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function previewPop(url){
    window.open (url,"Invoice","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=850,height=550");
}
</script>
```

This take my url as

```
http://test.study.com/shop1/public/report/generatepreview/report_date/2011%2F10%2F20
```

which result "`Object not found!`". So here i want to post the data instead of append it in url . how can i done here in zend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http://test.study.com/shop1/public/report/generatepreview/report_date/2011%2F10%2F20
```

Is not very nice URL, try Unix timestamp or current time millis or another format of date.

like:

- 20111020 - YYYYMMDD
- MjAxMSAxMCAyMA== base64 encoded version of 2011 10 20 (you can dismiss equations)
- 1319379406 - unix timestamp (curently UTC)

and decode it in Controller while proccessing data